# JavaScript - prevent elastic scrolling effect?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, scroll, mouse

I have a `wheel` event setup but if you are using OS X, the event continues to fire because of the native elastic effect.

How do I prevent this elastic effect?
Here is some code...

```
window.addEventListener('wheel',function(){
    pxCount++;
    var starContainer = 
    document.getElementById('starContainer').style.left = '-'+50*pxCount+'px';
  });
```

Here is the entire project http://codepen.io/www139/pen/wKbOJz

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your listener in a debounce function, the purpose of which being that a certain action is only performed once in a given time limit.

I'm a fan of this one: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

You'd probably use it like this:

```
var wheelAction = debounce(function() {
    pxCount++;
    var starContainer = 
    document.getElementById('starContainer').style.left = '-'+50*pxCount+'px';
}, 250);

window.addEventListener('wheel', wheelAction);
```

Comment: I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Great. I don't have an OS X machine, or I would have given it a go myself!

Comment: @www139 Did that help?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, I had an idea which I'm going to try which I think could work :)

Comment: @www139 That's a pity. Don't forget to write your own answer if you find a solution!

Comment: Thank you. I think I have seen this before somewhere, maybe it will work in another situation :) Thank you for all your help. (I gave you  +1 yesterday).

Comment: No problem! Sorry I couldn't help much

Comment: Don't worry about it, I may not even be able to figure it out in which case I'll try some other tactic but you actually gave be an idea that I'm going to try later today :)